# How to pass foreach data to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, local-storage

I have stored two `JSON` arrays in local storage i.e,
`viewbody=>json data1` , `viewcollar=>json data2`. I am fetching these arrays in `foreach` loop from local storage with data name attribute dynamically. But am not able to pass two `arrays` data to `php` `ajax`. Kindly help me, someone.

Below is my code,

```
$(document).on('click','.startDesignbtn', function() {
  var product_id = $(this).data("id");
  $(".getoption").each(function(){
    var option_name  = $(".getoption").data("name");
     // alert(option_name);
      var views = localStorage.getItem("view"+option_name);
    });

    $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=product/design/designMultiImage',
    type: 'post',
    //dataType: 'text',
    data:{
      'product_id': product_id,
      'views' : views,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);return false;
      var intValArray = data.split(',');
      var count = 0;
      $.each(intValArray,function(i){      
        localStorage.setItem("view_"+count,intValArray[i]);
        count++;
      });
      localStorage.setItem('design-image',data);
      localStorage.setItem('parent-id',product_id);
     // var custom_link = data;
      window.location = "<?php echo $customize_link;?>";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `var views = localStorage.getItem("view"+option_name);` - every time you run this, you create a new variable "views" within the scope of the .each loop. You need to create an array inside the "click" function and then assign the result of `localStorage.getItem("view"+option_name);` to the next space in the array (using .push()) every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

Use array.push() to append values to an array.  Also, you need to define the array outside of the each loop otherwise you reset it every time.  Also, inside the loop, use $(this) as opposed to targeting the element by class.  Fixed your click function below:

```
$(document).on('click','.startDesignbtn', function() {
  var product_id = $(this).data("id");
  var views = [];
  $(".getoption").each(function(){
    var option_name  = $(this).data("name");
     // alert(option_name);


      views.push("view"+option_name);


    });

    $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=product/design/designMultiImage',
    type: 'post',
    //dataType: 'text',
    data:{
      'product_id': product_id,
      'views' : views,
    },
    success: ...
```